# How to determine what limits the throughput of a local HTTP server?

Tags: networking, lan, http

I am trying to understand what limits the download speed of a local (LAN) HTTP server. If I have files on one PC, why can't I transfer them to another PC on my network as fast as the local connection allows?

I have set up a few http servers on my LAN (Python SimpleHTTPServer, npm http-server, Caddy) and I can download a file from the server at around 160 Mbps. I then use iperf to test out the bandwidth achievable on my LAN and I get around 700 Mbps.

I assume the throughput is limited either by hardware or the server configuration. Both the server and client have an SSD with r/w speeds that should be able to keep up.

How do I determine what limits my LAN http server file download speed to ~160 Mbps and not up to 700 Mbps?

Comment: Did you test while limiting iperf to one thread?

Comment: @harrymc I am using iperf3, which they state is single threaded unlike iperf2.